# Create file and write to, filename is user input?

Tags: c++, input, fstream

So I came on here earlier asking about a school assignment that involved reading each character from a file. That issue was fixed, but now I have encountered another problem.
Part of my assignment is to take in a user inputted file name, then set that file name to a text file that will be outputted with the results of the program.
Here is the program itself:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int fileNameSize = 20;
    int fileCount = 0;
    int testcount = 0;
    const string outName;
    std::ifstream inFile;
    std::ofstream outFile;
    <a bunch of other stuff>
            outFile.open(outName);
            int chartotal = acount + tcount + ecount + ocount + icount + ncount + scount + hcount + rcount;
            outFile << "File name: " << inputFileName << endl;
            outFile << "Number of E's: " << ecount << endl;
            outFile << "Number of T's: " << tcount << endl;
            outFile << "Number of A's: " << acount << endl;
            outFile << "Number of O's: " << ocount << endl;
            outFile << "Number of I's: " << icount << endl;
            outFile << "Number of N's: " << ncount << endl;
            outFile << "Number of S's: " << scount << endl;
            outFile << "Number of H's: " << hcount << endl;
            outFile << "Number of R's: " << rcount << endl;
            outFile << "Total Number of Characters: " << chartotal << endl;
            outFile << "--------------------------------" << endl;
            outFile.close();
            return 0;
        }
        inFile.close();
        inFile.clear();
    }
    //cout << "exit colm flag";
    //cout << "exit row flag\n";

}
```

It's my understanding that `outFile.open(outName);` should create a new file with the file name set as `outName`, however I just get a huge long error whenever I compile.
What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Here is the error I recieve

```
closed4Ahrens.cpp: In function 'int main()':
closed4Ahrens.cpp:19:9: error: no match for 'operator>>' in 'std::cin >> outName'
closed4Ahrens.cpp:19:9: note: candidates are:
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/istream:122:7: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& (*)(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/istream:122:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const string {aka const std::basic_string<char>}' to 'std::basic_istream<char>::__istream_type& (*)(std::basic_istream<char>::__istream_type&) {aka std::basic_istream<char>& (*)(std::basic_istream<char>&)}'
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/istream:126:7: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type& (*)(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>, std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type = std::basic_ios<char>]
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/istream:126:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const string {aka const std::basic_string<char>}' to 'std::basic_istream<char>::__ios_type& (*)(std::basic_istream<char>::__ios_type&) {aka std::basic_ios<char>& (*)(std::basic_ios<char>&)}'
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/istream:133:7: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/istream:133:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const string {aka const std::basic_string<char>}' to 'std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&)'
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/istream:169:7: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(bool&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/istream:169:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const string {aka const std::basic_string<char>}' to 'bool&'
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/istream:173:7: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(short int&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/istream:173:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const string {aka const std::basic_string<char>}' to 'short int&'
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/istream:176:7: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(short unsigned int&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/istream:176:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const string {aka const std::basic_string<char>}' to 'short unsigned int&'
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/istream:180:7: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(int&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/istream:180:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const string {aka const std::basic_string<char>}' to 'int&'
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/istream:183:7: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(unsigned int&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/istream:183:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const string {aka const std::basic_string<char>}' to 'unsigned int&'
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/istream:187:7: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(long int&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/istream:187:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const string {aka const std::basic_string<char>}' to 'long int&'
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/istream:191:7: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(long unsigned int&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/istream:191:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const string {aka const std::basic_string<char>}' to 'long unsigned int&'
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/istream:196:7: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(long long int&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/istream:196:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const string {aka const std::basic_string<char>}' to 'long long int&'
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/istream:200:7: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(long long unsigned int&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/istream:200:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const string {aka const std::basic_string<char>}' to 'long long unsigned int&'
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/istream:205:7: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(float&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/istream:205:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const string {aka const std::basic_string<char>}' to 'float&'
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/istream:209:7: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(double&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/istream:209:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const string {aka const std::basic_string<char>}' to 'double&'
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/istream:213:7: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(long double&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/istream:213:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const string {aka const std::basic_string<char>}' to 'long double&'
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/istream:217:7: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(void*&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/istream:217:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const string {aka const std::basic_string<char>}' to 'void*&'
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/istream:241:7: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__streambuf_type*) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__streambuf_type = std::basic_streambuf<char>]
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/istream:241:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const string {aka const std::basic_string<char>}' to 'std::basic_istream<char>::__streambuf_type* {aka std::basic_streambuf<char>*}'
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/bits/basic_string.tcc:998:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/bits/istream.tcc:957:5: note: template<class _CharT2, class _Traits2> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, _CharT2*)
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/bits/istream.tcc:925:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, _CharT&)
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/istream:709:5: note: template<class _Traits> std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>&, unsigned char&)
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/istream:714:5: note: template<class _Traits> std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>&, signed char&)
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/istream:756:5: note: template<class _Traits> std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>&, unsigned char*)
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/istream:761:5: note: template<class _Traits> std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>&, signed char*)
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/iomanip:70:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::_Resetiosflags)
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/iomanip:100:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::_Setiosflags)
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/iomanip:131:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::_Setbase)
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/iomanip:169:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::_Setfill<_CharT>)
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/iomanip:199:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::_Setprecision)
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/iomanip:229:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::_Setw)
closed4Ahrens.cpp:68:24: error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ofstream<char>::open(const string&)'
closed4Ahrens.cpp:68:24: note: candidate is:
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/fstream:702:7: note: void std::basic_ofstream<_CharT, _Traits>::open(const char*, std::ios_base::openmode) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::ios_base::openmode = std::_Ios_Openmode]
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/fstream:702:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const string {aka const std::basic_string<char>}' to 'const char*'
```

Update: I deleted the `const` in `const string outName`, now the error message is much shorter

```
closed4Ahrens.cpp:68:24: error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ofstream<char>::open(std::string&)'
closed4Ahrens.cpp:68:24: note: candidate is:
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/fstream:702:7: note: void std::basic_ofstream<_CharT, _Traits>::open(const char*, std::ios_base::openmode) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::ios_base::openmode = std::_Ios_Openmode]
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/fstream:702:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' to 'const char*'
```

Update 2: I've done as Paul Evans suggested

```
string outFileName;
ifstream inFile;
ofstream outFile;
char inputFileName [fileNameSize+1];
cout << "How many files are being processed?\n";
cin >> fileCount;
cout << "What is the output file name?\n";
cin >> outFileName;
const string outName(outFileName);
```

and

```
outFile.open(outName);
```

And now I am receiving this error message:

```
closed4Ahrens.cpp: In function 'int main()':
closed4Ahrens.cpp:70:17: error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ofstream<char>::open()'
closed4Ahrens.cpp:70:17: note: candidate is:
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/fstream:702:7: note: void std::basic_ofstream<_CharT, _Traits>::open(const char*, std::ios_base::openmode) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::ios_base::openmode = std::_Ios_Openmode]
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/fstream:702:7: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
```

Comment: you forgot to tell us what the error is

Comment: The error specifics seem kind of relevant here, eh?

Comment: please read about [mcve]. Most of your code is irrelevant to the question. On the other hand the error message is relevant, you should include it in the question.

Comment: Error message has been added.

Comment: In general I would advise you to test small parts of code before writing a wall of code just to realize that there is an error somewhere. If you know how to create a file and write "Hello World" to it then in principle you also know how to write any other output to it.

Comment: remove the `const` in `const std::string outName;`

Comment: also, unless you are building with c++11, you need `outFile.open(outName.c_str());`

Answer (score 0):

Your telling the compiler that `outfile` is `const` without initializing it, don't do that.  Do this instead:

```
 const string outName{"The path of the outfile"};
```

or

```
string outFileName;
// get outFileName
const string outName{outFileName};
```

Comment: Do I need `outFile.open` before this? Also what would be the path if it's supposed to go into the same directory as the program, just empty brackets?

Comment: Yes, you need to get the correct filename, then pass it into an `open`.  As your code says for `outfile,open(...)`.  But the main problem is defining a variable as `const` and not initializing it.

Comment: `outFile.open(outName);`, is this the proper syntax? Because it's still yielding errors for me.